# Is it more efficent to use a linked list and delete nodes or use an array and do a small computation to a string to see if element can be skipped?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

I am writing a program in C that reads a file. Each line of the file is a string of characters to which a computation will be done. The result of the computation on a particular string may imply that strings latter on in the file do not need any computations done to them. Also if the reverse of the string comes in alphabetical order before the (current, non-reversed) string then it does not need to be checked.

My question is would it be better to put each string in a linked list and delete each node after finding particular strings don’t need to be checked or using an array and checking the last few characters of a string and if it is alphabetically after the string in the previous element skip it? Either way the list or array only needs to be iterated through once.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're talking about? With some (pseudo-) code, perhaps? What "computation" are you doing on the strings? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're doing from this abstract description.

Answer (score 3):

Rules of thumb is that if you are dealing with small objects (< 32 bytes), std::vector is better than a linked list for most of general operations.

But for larger objects, (say, 1K bytes), generally you need to consider lists.

There is an article details the comparison you can check , the link is here

http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list/3/

Answer (score 0):

Without further details about what are your needs is a bit difficult to tell you which one would fit more with your requirements.

Arrays are easy to access, specially if you are going to do it in a non sequential way, but they are hard to maintain if you need to perform deletions on it or if you don't have a good approximation of the final number of elements.

Lists are good if you plan to access them sequentially, but terrible if you need to jump between its elements. Also deletion over them can be done in constant time if you are already in the node you want to delete.

I don't quite understand how you plan to access them since you say that either one would be iterated just once, but if that is the case then either structure would give you the similar performance since you are not really taking advantage of their key benefits.

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you should create an array of records, with each record holding one of your strings and a boolean flag to indicate whether it should be processed.

You set each record's flag to true as you load the array from the file.

You use one pointer to scan the array once, processing only the strings from records whose flags are still true.

For each record processed, you use a second pointer to scan from the first pointer + 1 to the end of the array, identify strings that won't need processing (in light of the current string), and set their flags to false.

-Al.