# Creating a linked list from objects in continuous memory

Tags: c++, performance, list, caching, vector

I want to iterate over objects which are stored very close together (to reduce cache misses). Would I be right in that I could achieve this by creating a vector so that all my objects are located continuously and then just create the linked list using references to X? This way I can insert to the head of the list very quickly and when i iterate through the list elements they won't be too far away from each other because they were all from the same vector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it more efficent to use a linked list and delete nodes or use an array and do a small computation to a string to see if element can be skipped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169468/is-it-more-efficent-to-use-a-linked-list-and-delete-nodes-or-use-an-array-and-do)

Comment: I'd think if the size of your vector is much larger than your L1 cache, all that jumping around between the vector might not be that beneficial. Otherwise it sounds like a fair assumption to make.

Comment: If you keep a linked list of vector elements you will have to update it every time your vector decides to change it's capacity (which causes realloc).

Comment: Why do you still need a linked list? Can't you use the vector directly?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Vector suits your need better than linked-list due to continuous memory storage. Iterating a vector and fetching its elements usually is much faster than linked list, providing items in the vector are not too big.

Comment: Thats not quite what I was saying- I am going to use a linked list on object references which were actually stored in a vector. The vector is just forcing continuous memory allocation. The linked list wrapper gives me quick insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need random access to each of the items in your storage, or sequential access.  How big is the memory storage, how many elements? How big is the longest element?

There are many ways to access your storage,

- raw sequential traversal of storage
- augment each storage element with a pointer to the next element
- augment each storage element with an offset (skip count) to the next element
- create a separate array (vector) of pointers into the storage
- create a separate array (vector) with offsets into the storage

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::vector` to store your nodes for a linked list can be a very useful and efficient strategy in some contexts, like one where you need to be able to remove elements from the middle in constant-time, still reclaim empty spaces, insert elements to the front/middle in constant-time, have traversal order match insertion order, preserve reasonably cache-friendly access patterns, and halve the memory use of links on 64-bit, like so:

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
     // Stores the memory for the element stored in the node.
     typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data;

     // Points to previous node in the array or previous
     // free node in the array if the node has been removed.
     // Stores -1 if there is no previous node.
     int32_t prev;

     // Points to next node in the array or next free
     // node in the array if the node has been removed.
     // Stores -1 if there is no next node.
     int32_t next;
};

template <class T>
struct List
{
    // Stores all the nodes contiguously.
    std::vector<Node<T>> nodes;

    // Points to the first node in the list.
    // Stores -1 if the list is empty.
    int32_t head;

    // Points to the first free node in the list.
    // Stores -1 if the free list is empty.
    int32_t free_head;
};
```

**`std::vector` as Memory Allocator**

In this case we are effectively sort of turning `std::vector` into our node memory allocator, and turning, say, 64-bit pointers storing absolute addresses into 32-bit indices storing relative indices to an array.

[image]

However, a downside to this solution as you can tell in my diagram above (sorry if it's a little confusing, that diagram represents what happens after erasing and reinserting) is that if you start erasing elements from the middle and reinserting and reclaimining vacant spaces, while you can continue to traverse elements in original insertion order, you start to incur more cache misses because following the links can have you starting to zig-zag back and forth in memory (no longer traversing the array in a perfect sequential access pattern). Same thing happens when you insert to the middle (this allows that to be done in constant-time, but the node in the middle might be allocated to the back of the array, and thus degrade locality of reference). That could lead to loading a memory region in a cache line only to evict it before all of it is used only to come back to the same memory region and load it again.

**Optimizing Pass**

So these types of "hybrid" array/linked-list solutions tend to have that downside of degrading in spatial locality the more you erase and insert elements to them from/to the middle. A way to mitigate that is occasionally make an "optimizing copy/swap" of the list every now and then which restores the spatial locality and gets you back to a point where every `prev` link is pointing to the previous index in the array, and every `next` link is pointing to the next.

**Still Much Better Than Usual**

Nevertheless, even without these "optimizing passes", it still tends incur much, much fewer cache misses even after many removals from the middle and reinsertions than a linked list whose nodes are allocated using a general-purpose allocator. In the latter case, the nodes could be scattered all over the place in memory to the point where you could incur a cache miss with every single node you access, and that's when you encounter the notoriety of linked lists to be particularly inefficient in many use cases. Also you get the benefit of using 32-bit indices (unless you actually need billions of nodes) instead of 64-bit pointers on 64-bit machines, halving the memory use of the links.

**Indexed Linked Lists**

I use linked lists a whole lot but they always use a solution like this, storing the nodes in contiguous arrays (either one contiguous buffer to store all the nodes, or a series of contiguous buffers which store 256 nodes each, e.g.), and often pointing to the nodes using relative indices rather than absolute pointers. When linked lists are used like this, they become much more efficient in practice.

**Memory Pools**

Back in 32-bit days I used to just use memory pools for this like a free list conforming to `std::allocator` for this purpose, but after 64-bit hardware became popular, the size of a pointer doubled in memory use and I found it much more useful to start using random-access data structures as the analogical "memory allocator" and relative 32-bit indices. Halving the size of a pointer is far from a trivial difference if the elements you are storing in the list are just 3 single-precision floats (12 bytes). The biggest practical nuisance I find is just having to work with indices to everything and not being able to get at the pointee data directly, since that would double memory use of links and wouldn't work if we use `std::vector` as our analogical memory allocator since it would invalidate the pointers every time it reallocated memory.

**swap-and-pop_back**

Note that if you don't care about traversal order, don't care about index invalidation, and don't need to be able to insert anywhere in constant-time, this data structure isn't so useful. In that case much more useful is just use a vector where you swap the element in the middle you want to remove with the last and `pop_back`. The main benefit of this structure is preserving constant-time removal from anywhere in the list, constant-time insertion to anywhere in the list, while simultaneously allowing you to traverse in original insertion order, and in a reasonably cache-friendly way.